# Automatically input root password using bash script

Tags: bash

I use the following bash script to run my local webserver on Fedora 29. After executing the script root password needs to be typed two times.

```
#!/bin/bash
systemctl enable httpd.service
systemctl start httpd.service
systemctl start mariadb.service
```

How can I save the root password inside above script and pass the same while prompted for?

Thanks in advance for your co-operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much better is to use `sudo` command and configure your user for passwordless execution of `systemctl` command

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl enable httpd.service
sudo systemctl start httpd.service
sudo systemctl start mariadb.service
```

Answer (score 1):

This is generally a bad idea, for many reasons. You shouldn't pass around passwords, let alone in plaintext. Also allowing passwordless execution of commands, let alone as `root` can be disastrous.
The suggestion by Romeo Ninov to configure `systemctl` to be executed without any prompts is absolutely forbidden when other people will have access to your system, and downright a bad practice even if you're working by yourself.

What's a better idea is to add a new entry to yout `sudoers` file, allowing you to call this script and its content using sudo, without prompting for your `root` password.

Check out [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt) post on how achieve this.